# How to programmatically build an org-chart and export to a PowerPoint file?

Tags: php, powerpoint, orgchart

Most of the question is in the title.

A client is asking me to build a form with dynamic hierarchical fields from which to build a sort of org-chart that must be exported to PPT (OpenOffice Impress is an option).

I've found many libraries that allows to do that, but all of them only allows to export to images, HTML5 or other non editable charts.

I'd really like to use Google Chart Tools (even though I'm afraid of Google tendency of discontinuing their products), but also this tool doesn't have any mean to export to PowerPoint.

Also PHPPowerPoint seems a possible solution, but there is no documentation as far as I can see and I don't know if the autoarrange requirement is available.

Being dynamically built, the library must also take care of automatically arranging all items (unless anyone knows a way to do that programmatically).

Does anyone ever had this need or know a possible approach?

The main point is that the generated file must be editable.

Comment: If Powerpoint is a requirement I'd think you'd use Office Automation for this

Comment: wouldn't be the same of using PHPPowerPoint? Either case, how can I use Office Automation in a LAMP server? And would this solve the "autoarrange" requirement? I don't think so.